# Wrong rendering in htmlAttributes of TextBoxFor method

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I would like to render a htmlAttribute as a boolean, my code is that:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m, new Dictionary<string, object>
{
    { "data-val", true }
})
```

but the result is:

```
<input data-val="True" id="Category_Name" name="Category.Name" type="text" value="">
```

Why is it rendering as a string?
How can I render it as boolean like this:

```
<input data-val=true id="Category_Name" name="Category.Name" type="text" value="">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will simply call the `ToString` method on the given object which is True or False (uppercase) for bool. So change the given example to:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m, new Dictionary<string, object>
{
    { "data-val", "true" }
})
```

Comment: But I need as a boolean cause jquery.unobtrusive parse the elements in view like that: 

$(selector).find(":input[data-val=true]").each(function () {
     $jQval.unobtrusive.parseElement(this, true);
});

Comment: There is no such thing as html attribute type. So there is no way to define the attribute type as 'boolean'. data-val=true is simply not correct (however it may work). data-val="true" is correct. Did you check your solution with this?

Comment: Yeah, when I use data-val="true" the unobtrusive find no elements. It only works with data-val=true.

Comment: What do you exactly mean of 'the unobtrusive find no element'? jQuery finds the element: http://jsfiddle.net/d7Xsb/

Comment: Ops, I mean data-val="True" as it is rendered :(

Comment: and is it work with "true"? So the string passed as parameter.

Comment: Yes, it is working with 'true' but not with 'True' so as it is rendered.